# php website mail form not getting to exchange server recipient -

Tags: php, forms, email, exchange-server

I picked this script because it had a CAPTCHA and file upload/attachment.  http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/php-contact-form-tutorial.html/comment-page-2#comments

I know it is older, and the script writer isn't support it on their website.

The form is at HostGator at web address (fake of course, just using it for example) "abcinc.com".  The company/website owner has their emails on an Exchange Server 2013 and is using "abc.com" for their mail.

The email the form creates - I receive it at my Google/Gmail accounts.  I've used this script on this server for half dozen other people (different website organizations) who receive them fine (either using the Google/Gmail, Hostgator mail).

This client can not receive these emails on their Exchange Server (2013) at "abc.com" (and yes, I have the email addresses in the form correctly).

I'm just trying to learn something. That is why I'm here.  I'm not a php programmer, I'm not a cPanel, Exchange Server or any kind of mail / server demi-god. All I know is I picked a script and modified it, hosted it at HostGator, and believed that when the form was used that HostGator sent the mail to whom evers email addresses are in the form.

The Exchange tech support people wrote me this:

> I need to know the SMTP service you are using to send the email and if
>   it is possible for you to use a real email address from ABC.com to
>   send the email from the form.
>
> Please take a look at the article below and try to mirror the settings
>   as best you can.  Also, please us an actual email address from
>   abcinc.com to send the email if possible.  I can create a new one for
>   you or you can use an existing one if you like.  After you have made
>   these changes or if you have any questions, please reach out to me so
>   we can do final testing.
>
> Here is a KB that has all the settings typically used for web
>   applications and other devices to be able to send using our servers.
>   If there web application is doing the sending portion, please see if
>   there are any logs available that may show
>       How To Configure Your Printer, Scanner, Copier, Web Script Or SMTP Application To Work With An Exchange Account
>   http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/viewKBArticle.asp?id=2167
>   Here are the specific settings for your account. Note: this is an
>   Exchange 2013 server.
>
> (I didn't include the settings here)

So after attempting to read through that my brain exploded.  When I recovered I logged on with HostGator support to ask them... hell I don't know what I was trying to ask them.

They told me to give them my cPanel IP.

I then asked the Exchange Server people if they could just give me a script they knew worked.  Yeah... I did.  :-\

So my question is - what is keeping this Exchange Server from receiving these emails?

Mostly so I can become ever so slightly more educated than I was 10 minutes ago.

~Kaye

PS / EDITED

I came back to add, I just tried another (basic) form and they received it.

From the form that was not getting to the Exchange Server, this is the header info:

```
To: jill@abc.com
Subject: Contact form submission from Kaye
X-PHP-Script: www.abcinc.com/estimates.php for 76.3.118.189
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2013 15:37:30 -0500
From: Kaye <nobody@www.abc.com>
Reply-To: kaye@mydomain.com
Message-ID: <be82ada010a752b86440e86e5c24ca0a@www.abcinc.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer (phpmailer.sourceforge.net) [version 2.0.4]
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
```

In the form that did work, it is using the actual email that the user enters into the form as the FROM email address - not the server.  Is this what could be the issue the Exchange Server is having?

```
function GetFromAddress()
{
    if(!empty($this->from_address))
    {
        return $this->from_address;
    }

    $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    $from ="nobody@$host";
    return $from;
}
```

Comment: I see things like this a lot. They are probably "white listing" certain servers that are acceptable to have email come from. This means that ONLY servers they have entered into the config files can send email to them. Just give them the information they asked for and they should be able to remedy the situation.

Comment: `From: Kaye <nobody@www.abc.com>` most likely is not a valid email address and they probably are looking for an MX record for `www.abc.com` which probably doesn't exist. Most likely your MX record is just for `abc.com`

Comment: `it is using the actual email that the user enters into the form as the FROM email address` does the domain name they are entering in have an SPF record limiting emails to only come from their server?

Comment: Pitchinnate - I will ask / investigate / digest what you wrote. :)

Answer (score 2):

Most hosted Exchange providers include filters that will check for SPF records—or MX records at a minimum—for the domain with which the sender address is associated.  Since there is most likely neither an SPF nor a MX record for www.[your-domain].com (because of the "www."), the hosted Exchange provider's SPAM blocker is marking the message as SPAM because it cannot verify that the IP address from which the message is coming is actually, legitimately associated with www.[your-domain].com—or, alternately (and perhaps more likely), that www.[your-domain].com has no MX or SPF records associated with it and thus the server assumes the message must be junk (because why would a domain name not configured for email be sending email?).  [your-domain].com might have those records, but that doesn't necessarily cover the "www." subdomain.

I've dealt with this in my own personal experience before and found that Google Apps would process messages that various hosted Exchange providers would not.  Some hosted Exchange providers do not even let you see what has been blocked (e.g. GoDaddy) and thus it makes it very difficult to troubleshoot.

Now, in your edited post, you mentioned that the script is now sending "from" the user-inputed address and that this has helped.  You are correct to assume this has helped.  Even though the sending IP address won't match the sender domain name, the receiving server likely has a policy to accept messages absent a specific reason not to (e.g. a blacklist entry or a complete lack of MX/SPF records for the domain name), even if the IP doesn't match the domain name.

These headers…

```
From: Kaye <nobody@www.abc.com>
Reply-To: kaye@mydomain.com
```

…are defective since the receiving server is mainly concerned with the "from" address.  The reply-to address, although it may be valid, adds no credibility to a message and the mail server will not take the time to look at it if the "from" address is invalid or blacklisted.

This header…

```
Message-ID: <be82ada010a752b86440e86e5c24ca0a@www.abcinc.com>
```

…won't make a difference either way, despite the "www." in it.  A Message-ID just needs to be unique and nothing else matters.

Comment: Ok, I'm back.  I was requested to join a conference call with their exchange server IT people - who talked way over my head.

I tried 3 different mail scripts from 3 different sources and the website owner COULD NOT receive any of them.  I can, their IT guy can (I have no idea what his mail set up is).  I tried this script (see item 4. Maybe It Is The Web Server)  http://www.simfatic.com/blog/simfatic-forms/262/no-emails-from-the-form/  and the site owner still did not receive it.

Is this an issue with how the hosting (outgoing mail) is configured, is it an error with the scripts?

Comment: @KBarnes, I noticed something in your example headers above.  The name "Kaye" is not wrapped in quotations marks.  I've had that omission cause mail to be undeliverable before.  Try getting it to output a header like this:

From: "Kaye" <nobody@abc.com>

Comment: @ohio818 what is the proper workaround for this problem?I have been banging my head with a similar problem